# Jenkins Maven Release suggestions

Tags: svn, jenkins, maven-3, release, maven-release-plugin

We use Jenkins to build and deploy our projects and we have not done a release yet. What I was thinking was Jenkins would read the parent POM and build the project modules, on release it would update all the project's modules versions, and create tags in the child module's tags directory. Is this possible and has anyone had experience with doing a Maven release on Jenkins with this kind of SVN structure?

We have the Maven Release Plugin on Jenkins right now.

An example of our SVN project structure:

```
Database  
-trunk
-pom.xml
--HibernateProject
---pom.xml 
--DatabaseSchemaProject
---pom.xml
-branches
-tags
```

Comment: I've done this before and as far as I remeber, if you start a release build on your parent project (Database) all submodules will be released too. You should however have only one version for the whole project defined in your parent. Don't know how Maven would handel it if all the modules had different versions.

Comment: Thanks I am trying it now in Jenkins. The prepare goal for the Maven release plugin works, it succeeds, but it fails on the perform. 409 Conflict sending artifacts to server. I did it a few times but when it kept failing to perform, I kept modifying the POM in trunk back to SNAPSHOT 1.0 instead of 1.1 and deleted tag Release 1.0. Is there a rollback on if the perform fails?

Comment: Normally it should rollback automatically if the perform fails. I think you release build performs very well but deploying the built artifacts to your Nexus (or whatever) fails.